# api-maps.yandex.ru загрузка через javascript

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

День добрый! Мне нужно карту из [конструктора](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/) загрузить с помощью JS либо как то узнать что карта загрузилась, как указывать DOM элемент в который карта должна загрузиться и как указывать коллбеки - не нашёл, вообще документации 0.

Все ведут сюда, а там...
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index-docpage/

В идеале хочу использовать `$.getScript(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем основном скрипте создаете элемент script, вешаете на него событие 'load', после того как скрипт будет загружен будет вызван колбэк, в котором пишите логику(на этом этапе скрипт уже загружен). В параметрах загружаемого конструктора указывается id контейнера в который необходимо вставить ваш конструктор (в примере 'id=mymap')

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const yandexScript = document.createElement('script');
  yandexScript.setAttribute(
    'src',
    'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A80d079877e1ccf70b87a4ddf83a992207f275df1a7040b2b4782c296d0faf859&amp;width=500&amp;height=400&amp;id=mymap&amp&lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true%22%3E%3C/script'
  );
  yandexScript.addEventListener('load', () => {
     console.log('карта загружена');
  });
  document.body.appendChild(yandexScript);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Пример с интерактивной картой в определенном контейнере</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>Карта</h1>
        <div id="mymap"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это всё прекрасно, но я про API конструктора спрашивал, вот например мне такой скрипт дают в этом конструкторе: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A80d079877e1ccf70b87a4ddf83a992207f275df1a7040b2b4782c296d0faf859&amp;width=500&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>

Но мне это надо вызвать программно

Comment: В атрибуте  src у создаваемого скрипта укажите URL вашего скрипта, а собственно логика то такая же, а в колбэке вызванном после загрузки, пишите нужную вам логику

Comment: Так а как вы создадите объект Map без загруженной библиотеки API ?

Comment: Да хорош, я понял... =) Только вот `load` не скрипта нужен, а именно карты и её содержимого, кажется там были такие события в API, но как их в параметры передать не пойму... `?param=1&param=2` ... `&callback=myCallback`
Ну это так на тему... а вообще пока работает вроде...

Comment: Если мой ответ вас устраивает, поставьте пожалуйста галочку: "принять ответ")

Comment: Да мне не жалко, спасибо!